# Extract images parts from GeoTIFF file using polygons in a shapefile

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, extract-by-mask, rioxarray

I would like to know if there is any way that I can extract images from a [GeoTIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTIFF) file using an [ESRI shapefile](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) which contains [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html) polygon data for specific locations in the image in [Python](https://www.python.org/).

I would like to extract an image per polygon in the shapefile. The closest I have gotten to this until now is using [`gdal_rasterize`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html) to mask out all the areas outside the Polygons and creating windows using [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: The rasterstats package will do this for you also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rioxarray. Here is an example: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html

Fiona example:

```py
import rioxarray
import fiona

xds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(...)
with fiona.open(...) as fds:
    for row in fds:
        clipped = xds.rio.clip([row["geometry"]], fds.crs_wkt)
        clipped.rio.to_raster(...)
```

geopandas example:

```py
import rioxarray
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import mapping

xds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(...)
gpd = geopandas.read_file(...)

for _, geom in gpd.geometry.apply(mapping).iteritems():
    clipped = xds.rio.clip([geom], gpd.crs)
    clipped.rio.to_raster(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The mask and rasterize code is good but you need to do it for each feature in the shapefile.

Open the shapefile using fiona and loop through individual features.

features = fiona.open("myshapefile.shp")

for polys in features:
     *masking and clip code here.*

This will give you a separate image for each polygon in the shapefile